# Six coins are tossed. Alice pays Betty...

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Six coins are tossed. Alice pays Betty according to the following table:

If no heads: $200

If 1 head: $50

If 2 heads: $10

If 3 heads: $5

If 4 heads: $20

If 5 heads: $25

If 6 heads: $80

If $X$ is the amount Alice pays, find $E(X)$

I have no idea how to start this

EDIT:

Okay so for 0 heads, we have $\binom{6}{0} * (\frac{1}{2})^{0} * (\frac{1}{2})^{6} = \frac{1}{64}$

1 heads: $\binom{6}{1} * (\frac{1}{2})^{1} * (\frac{1}{2})^{5} = \frac{3}{32}$

2 heads: $\binom{6}{2} * (\frac{1}{2})^{2} * (\frac{1}{2})^{4}= \frac{15}{64}$

3 heads: $\binom{6}{3} * (\frac{1}{2})^{3} * (\frac{1}{2})^{3} = \frac{5}{16}$

4 heads: $\binom{6}{4} * (\frac{1}{2})^{4} * (\frac{1}{2})^{2} = \frac{15}{64}$

5 heads: $\binom{6}{5} * (\frac{1}{2})^{5} * (\frac{1}{2})^{1} = \frac{3}{32}$

6 heads: $\binom{6}{6} * (\frac{1}{2})^{6} * (\frac{1}{2})^{0} = \frac{1}{64}$

Then I take each of these values and multiply it with X right? So for example, for 0 heads which is $\frac{1}{64}$, I multiply it with 200, then add it with $\frac{3}{32} * 50$ for 1 heads, etc.?

Comment: Are you able to calculate the probability for no head, 1 head, 2 heads, ...? Key word: Binomial distribution. Now it´s your turn!

Comment: Well the thing I'm confused about is whether or not we have bernoulli trials. It says we toss 6 coins, rather than 1 coin 6 times in a row, so we're just tossing a total of 6 coins in one go. Each coin has a 1/2 chance of being heads or tails, and since there are 6 coins, then the probability is $\frac{1}{2}^{6}$?

Comment: Yes, tossing the coins one after another is the same as tossing them all at the same time.

Comment: @Stuy Yes, but this is only a part of the binomial distribution. You forgot the binomial coefficient. What is the prob. that $1$ coin is head?

Comment: Oh okay, so since we do have Bernoulli Trials, for 0 heads it would be $\binom{6}{0} * (\frac{1}{2})^{0}*(\frac{1}{2})^{5}$?

Comment: @Stuy That´s true. Let  $P(X=x)=\binom{6}{x} * (\frac{1}{2})^{x}*(\frac{1}{2})^{6-x}$ Then the expected value is $E(X)=\sum\limits_{x=0}^6 p_x\cdot P(X=x)$, where $p_x$ are the corresponding payments.

Comment: Can you guys check my edit

Comment: @Stuy That´s right what you´ve written at your edit.

Comment: @Stuy, you can post (and even accept, I think) an answer to your own question.